# How to put function in React className field?

Tags: reactjs, styles, classname

I've got something like this:

```
const [valueA, setValA] = useState(1)
const [valueB, setValB] = useState(1)


const classHandler = (val) => {

    if (val<2) {
        return 'styles.redButt'
    } else if (val===2) {
        return 'styles.normalButt'
    } else if (val===5) {
        return 'styles.greenButt'
    } else {
        return 'styles.noneButt'
    }
}

return (<>
    <div className={classHandler(valueA), styles.buttonize}>
        FIRST INFO {valueA}
    </div>
    <div className={classHandler(valueB), styles.buttonize}>
        SECOND INFO {valueB}
    </div>

</>)
```

Function doesn't work, but no errors, and second class {styles.buttonize} works just fine!
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) (,) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand. In your case `classHandler(valueA)` is evaluated but `className` will be equal to styles.buttonize (last operand).

If you are using `css modules`, this `return 'styles.redButt'`, won't work, instead use `return styles.redButt`

```
const classHandler = (val) => {
  if (val<2) {
        return styles.redButt
    } else if (val===2) {
        return styles.normalButt
    } else if (val===5) {
        return styles.greenButt
    } else {
        return styles.noneButt
    }
}
<div className={`${classHandler(valueA)} ${styles.buttonize}`}>
        FIRST INFO {valueA}
</div>
```

Comment: Yesss! Thank You! I know I was close.... but without your help... ;-)